# Удаление элемента в generic array

Tags: java, generics

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
        numbers.add(45);
        numbers.add(78);
        numbers.add(10);
        numbers.add(17);
        numbers.add(89);
        numbers.add(16);


        System.out.println(numbers);

        numbers.removeAt(3);

        System.out.println(numbers);

    }
}




import java.util.Arrays;

public class ArrayList<T> {
    private static final int DEFAULT_SIZE = 6;


    private T[] elements;
    private int size;

    public ArrayList() {
        this.elements = (T[])new Object[DEFAULT_SIZE];
        this.size = 0;
    }

    /**
     * Добавляет элемент в конец списка
     * @param element добавляемый элемент
     */
    public void add(T element) {
        // если массив уже заполнен
        if (isFullArray()) {
            resize();
        }

        this.elements[size] = element;
        size++;
    }

    private void resize() {
        // запоминаем старый массив
        T[] oldElements = this.elements;
        // создаем новый массив, который в полтора раза больше предыдущего
        this.elements = (T[])new Object[oldElements.length + oldElements.length / 2];
        // копируем все элементы из старого массива в новый
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            this.elements[i] = oldElements[i];
        }
    }

    private boolean isFullArray() {
        return size == elements.length;
    }

    /**
     * Получить элемент по индексу
     * @param index индекс искомого элемента
     * @return элемент под заданным индексом
     */
    public T get(int index) {
        if (isCorrectIndex(index)) {
            return elements[index];
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private boolean isCorrectIndex(int index) {
        return index >= 0 && index < size;
    }

    public void clear() {
        this.size = 0;
    }


    public void removeAt(int index)  {

        elements.remove(elements[index]);
        }

    public String toString() { return Arrays.toString(elements); }
}
```

[image: Не получается удалить элемент массива. Подскажите пожалуйста, где ошибка?]

Comment: remove надо прописывать самостоятельно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Массивы в Java *никогда не имели* метод `remove` равно как и `add`, так как у них *всегда* фиксированный размер, задаваемый при создании массива.   Этот размер и возвращается полем `.length`.

При необходимости уменьшить размер массива при удалении элемента/нескольких элементов сперва надо декрементировать `size`, затем сдвинуть оставшиеся элементы влево (к началу массива) и, при достижении определённого порога (например `size < length / 2`), создавать массив меньшего размера, копируя в него оставшиеся элементы.

Answer (score 0):

Получился вот такой рабочий код

```
public void removeAt(int index)  {
        if (index  < 0 || index > this.size) {
            return;
        }

        T[] clippedElements = (T[])new Object[this.size - 1];
        int clippedElementsIdx = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (i != index) {
                clippedElements[clippedElementsIdx++] = elements[i];
            }
        }
        this.elements = clippedElements;
        this.size--;
    }
```

Всем спасибо!